# How do you set MKMapView region on current location and follow user location?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have a button that centers the map and sets the region based on the user's current location and then sets the user tracking mode to follow. I am following the user while moving and if they move the map or zoom out it sets the user tracking mode to none.

This is what I have

```
guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else { return }
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentLocation.coordinate,
                                          latitudinalMeters: regionRadius,
                                          longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)
map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
map.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: true)
```

It successfully sets the region back to the user's current location and then the user tracking mode to follow but for some reason it doesn't follow anymore.

Comment: How does your device know that user's location has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for setRegion animation to finish so it doesn't mess with setUserTrackingMode.

```
guard let currentLocation = locationManager.location else { return }
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: currentLocation.coordinate, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius)

MKMapView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
    self.map.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}) { _ in
    self.map.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.follow, animated: false)
}
```